# Selector [ng\:model="test"] did not match any elements

Tags: angularjs

I want to run an e2e-test using angular.
This is my html file:

```
<html>
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thread>
<tr>
.
.
.
<th class="icon">
<i ng-click="test" ng-show="isQuestionEditable()" class="icon-plus"></i>
</th>
</tr>
</thread>
</div>
</html>
```

How do I call ng-click properly?
I tried:

```
it('test', function(){
  element('test').click();
});
```

But I get the error message: Selector [ng\:model="test"] did not match any elements.

I am accessing the right page for sure. I wrote:

```
beforeEach(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('/');
    });
```

'/' being proxied as `http://localhost:8080/test`

Comment: Do you have a model assigned to the element?

Answer (score 1):

One work around would be to give the button an `id="button"` and then your selector would be `element('#button')`.

Also check the caveat at the bottom of http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

Its hard to tell from your example if you are manually bootstrapping `angular` or using ng-app.